# having trouble with LoadToolBarEx function of the CMFCToolBar class and set ID for the COpenGLControl class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, icons, toolbar

I have created a new empty dialog to test the code [Some notes on CMFCToolBar – Docking Large Buttons and use of the MDIClientArea](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615473/Some-notes-on-CMFCToolBar-Docking-Large-Buttons-an) but I see that this line produces `false`:

```
bool b = m_FirstToolbar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_MAINFRAME, tbi, TRUE);
```

and this is the resources of my project:

[image]
**what's the problem and what should I add to the resources?**
please help me. this is the third question that I ask today about toolbars on an MFC dialog based application.
[My toolbar on a dialog based mfc application is not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074632/my-toolbar-on-a-dialog-based-mfc-application-is-not-shown)
[after writing the code to add a toolbar to a dialog-based mfc the dialog doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073052/after-writing-the-code-to-add-a-toolbar-to-a-dialog-based-mfc-the-dialog-doesnt)
and I have read many questions on this site and also studied lots of pages on the web. finally I came to the point to use `CMFCToolBar` class instead of `CToolbar` to support 32bit 24x24 icons for the toolbar but none of the pages helped really and I haven't still seen the toolbar at top of my dialog.
**Could you please help me introduce a link,a video tutorial and etc which has taught adding toolbars that support icons of 32bit images in Visual studio 2010 to a dialog-based mfc application **

**I'd prefer a tutorial which has started from scratch and is good for a beginner of MFC as well a to aguru**

### thanks.I'd be glad to here your answers.

**Edited section of my question based on @Edward Clements useful guidances**
this is my project's Resource.h file

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by InitialJobProject2.rc
//
#define IDM_ABOUTBOX                    0x0010
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100
#define IDS_ABOUTBOX                    101
#define IDD_INITIALJOBPROJECT2_DIALOG   102
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     130
#define IDR_TOOLBAR1                    132
#define IDI_ICON1                       135
#define IDC_NewBtnTbr                   135
#define IDC_ZoomInBtnTbr                136
#define IDC_ZoomOutBtnTbr               137
#define IDI_ICON2                       138
#define IDC_PanBtnTbr                   138
#define IDC_TXTDataFile                 1001
#define IDC_EDTDataPath                 1002
#define IDC_BTNBrowse                   1003
#define IDC_RICHEDTHeader               1005
#define IDC_OPENGL                      1009

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        139
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32776
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1010
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           104
#endif
#endif
```

I don't know how the numbers are set? and how should I compute the number to assign to the new ID?
what's the difference between `_APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE`,`_APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE`,`_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` and `_APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE`?
and if I assign the number 1010 to the new ID then what should I write in front of `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE`?
and one more question that rose up is this one:

### I have used the [MFC/C++ Helper Class for Window Resizing from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125068/MFC-C-Helper-Class-for-Window-Resizing#xx4346903xx) to anchor controls of dialog to it. This class uses ID of controls. and I have added a [COpenGLControl from codeguru for Setting Up OpenGL in an MFC Control](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) which does not need ID in its constructor but since it is derived from CWnd class,it has a function `setHelpID`Could I add this way an`IDM,IDB,IDD,IDR,IDS,IDI or IDC` (I don't know which one please help me how to choose between them`and then assign this ID through function`setHelpID`to the instance of the class`COpenglControl`? and then use this ID to hook the openGL window to the main window through class`CWndResizer`?

**Problem solved

the way that I suggested for setting ID for the opengl window does work except that you should use SetDlgCtrlID member function instead of SetHelpID**

Comment: notice that `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` = `IDC_OPENGL + 1`, that's for controls (like controls in dialog boxes, toolbar-buttons, etc), `_APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE` = next resource ID to allocate for dialog boxes, `_APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE` ditto for menuitems, so when you manually enter a value in resource.h, increment the proper '_APS_NEXT_...`value accordingly -- e.g.: if you assign the number 1010 to the a new control ID, then you should change `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` to 1011 -- sorry, I have no experience of OpenGL, maybe you should ask a new question once you have the dialog up and running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with loading toolbars into a dialog, but you need to create a Toolbar resource with an ID (I would not use `IDR_MAINFRAME` myself since it is confusing and you may need multiple toolbars) and use this ID in `LoadToolBarEx`; the toolbar would contain buttons with their own images and IDs. You will need a `ON_COMMAND` and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` in your message map to enable/disable the buttons and to respond to the button clicks.

[This MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/145a84ad-ac2d-4afb-8448-595cf31cc5a6/bug-with-cmfctoolbar) mentions that your dialog needs to be derived from `CDialogEx` instead of `CDialog`.

There's very little clear documentation on the MFC Featurepack Controls (like CMFCToolbar), this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217588/Porting-a-legacy-MFC-app-to-MFC-Feature-Pack) might help (even though it's about porting a legacy application, it still has quite a lot of useful do's and dont's).

Some more info in ths [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063156/is-it-possible-to-add-cmfctoolbar-to-a-dialog), this is about creating toolbars dynamically (without having a toolbar resource).

Comment: thanks @Edward Clements. my dialog is created in VS2010 and I have derived it from CDialogEx but the main trouble is I have tried creating toolbars dynamically as the way suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489537/why-i-cant-catch-the-toolbar-events) but it doesn't work.there's an error with CMFCToolBarButton constructor which tells that no instances of this overloaded function matches the argument list because the first button would be the ID of a CMFCToolBarButton but it isn't because I'm just creating the button here in this function!where should I set the ID of button

Comment: (continued the previous comment in this) before calling the constructor and how?

Comment: The first parameter to the `CMFCToolBarButton` constructor is the ID, you need to supply it even when you construct it dynamically becase you would later need to respond to this ID when the button is clicked. You can supply a pre #defined IDC_xxx value for this. You will need a `ON_COMMAND` and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` in your message map for each button to enable/disable the buttons and to respond to the button clicks.

Comment: ok thanks @Edward Clements I have opened resource.h file of my solution should I define the IDC_xxx here? Is there any risk if I modify this source.h manually?

Comment: No, not at all -- be careful to update `_APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE` at the end of Resource.h file to the last ID you used + 1

Comment: thanks @Edward Clements excuse me asking so many questions! I'm new to MFC and this is my first application. please see edited section of my question. I don't know what you mean by be careful to update _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE at the end of Resource.h file to the last ID you used + 1 and I have explained the problem in the edited section more detailed.